# Hide Choose Tracker options when the user clicks away

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

When I view my own profile on the "activity" tab, the top left box contains my reputation. It also contains the ability to track your next privilege or badge.
When you click on the *cog* the following appears:

[image: track options]

Currently if you click away from this box, nothing happens. You have to either click the remaining half of the button or click the existing ticked option to remove the pop-up.

My proposal is that clicking away from this box should hide the pop-up options.

Comment: Where exactly is this? Your screenshot doesn't give very much context, and I'm having trouble locating it on my profile.

Comment: Well that is odd. My profile looks completely different. Where you have a cog button, [I have a line graph and some bars indicating my progress towards the badge](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jRTEi.png). *(brb, have to go answer a question tagged [visual-studio)*

Comment: @CodyGray - to the right of the tag badge bars, there is a cog where you can select to follow either a privilege or tag badge, but I'm guessing since you already have all the privileges there isn't the option for you :) ([Example image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kGPPB.png))